# Enable onboard ATI xpress 200 with GeForce 7800 PCIe?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce

The MSI motherboard in my HP dx5150MT computer has onboard ATI xpress 200 graphics and a PCIe slot. Since installing a GeForce 7800 card into the PCIe slot my onboard graphics have disappeared.

I'm using Windows XP and as far as I can tell I've installed all the latest drivers.

**Is it possible to re-enable my onboard graphics card to work along-side the PCIe card?** If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most motherboards do not support using both PCIe graphics as well as the on-board graphics.  It's almost always one or the other.